# Does this sentence sound awkward?

Tags: sentence-structure

> She is feeling her tummy hurt from lunch time.

Or

> Her tummy is hurting since her lunch time.

Which one sounds more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say:

> Her **stomach** *has been* hurting since lunch time.

Comment: Thanks! Why didnt I think about using 'has been'!?

Answer (score 0):

*Tummy* sounds very childish and unless this is how you intend it to sound, I would say:

*Her stomach hurts since lunch.*

Comment: Thanks! I used that word because I work with children !  I was confused when I reported her condition to teacher!

Answer (score 0):

"Her stomach has been hurting since lunch time" is correct.

However, "Her stomach hurts since lunch" is not, because "since lunch" indicates that the action started in the past and is ongoing, which would require the present perfect tense in this case.